# What is this embedded ruby delimiter? -%>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

"`-%>`" appears in some code in a tutorial I'm doing, as a delimiter of some embedded ruby, like this:

```
<% 5.times do |i| -%>
    <%= thumbnail_tag slideshow.slides[i] %>
<% end -%>
```

What does it mean? There's nothing in the book about it (*Rails Up and Running*)

Comment: This isn't a ruby delimiter, but rather a delimiter for the template language. Which templating language are you using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The template language ERB supports `<%-` and `-%>` in addition to the Ruby code delimiters `<%` and `%>`.

Adding a minus to the inner side of the delimiter strips whitespace from the HTML next to the outer side of the delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

In ERB it removes any newline that follows from the output.